# Zope AdvancedQuery ICatalogTool

Tags: python, zope

I have an ICatalogTool, and catalog which I could query using AdvancedQuery and I want to learn how to use this tool, which queries I could use to find something in that Catalog.

I have an example of usage of this tool:

```
results = ICatalogTool(dc).search(query=Eq('id', self._object.ip))

# Eq - is an "EQUALS" in AdvancedQuery
# dc - instance of DeviceList class
# self._object.ip - some IP for search
```

I have read a documentation and found that each function like Eq takes some index. So I want to know which other indexes except `'id'` are in my catalog. How to look for that? Are there some tools for introspection?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Zope Management Interface in the Indexes tab.  Otherwise, you can list index names programmatically by calling the `indexes()` method of the catalog object.

*IMHO, you should familiarize with the basic query interface (calling `searchResults()` method using queries specified as mappings) before attempting to use the AdvancedQuery add-on.*

Comment: I've tried to find these indexes, but had no result. Could you please help me with search of indexes?

I mean, could you please give me a piece of code which will find the indexes?

Comment: I've given you method names for objects you are already able to obtain.  Otherwise, there are plenty of docs on zope.org and plone.org,  the fine manual in this case: http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/SearchingZCatalog.html